# how to add a new element in RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a spark pair RDD (key, count) as below

```
Array[(String, Int)] = Array((a,1), (b,2), (c,3), (d,4))
```

i want to add a new **max** element in RDDs

```
Array[(String, Int)] = Array((a,1,4), (b,2,4), (c,3,4), (d,4,4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the definition, you are saying:

`(a, 1)` -> `(a, 1, 4)`

`(b, 2)` -> `(b, 2, 4)`

`(c, 1)` -> `(c, 3, 4)` where is the 3 coming from now?

`(d, 3)` -> `(d, 4, 4)` where is the 4 coming from now?

In case your new `max` is the maximum value of your value `RDD` plus one, then you can sort descending by value and get the value of the first element:

```
val max = df1.sortBy(_._2, ascending = false).collect(0)._2 + 1 

val df2 = df1.map(r => (r._1, r._2, max)
```

This gives:

```
(a,1,4)
(b,2,4)
(c,1,4)
(d,3,4)
```

which should be what you want.